# Getting one row insted of multiple rows when using query statment inside in() at where clause

Tags: mysql, group-concat, sql-in

There are two tables fruits and fruits_seasons in the schema and I wanted to get all the monsoon fruits. While trying so I noticed a weird response.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77d52b2736a04a5adf4ffe80881cd4ab

Monsoon months

```
select group_concat(fruit_id) from fruits_seasons where monsoon = 1;
```

| group_concat(fruit_id) |
| --- |
| 2,8,9,11,13,15 |

*The query I used*

```
SELECT 
        f.name AS name, f.price AS price
    FROM
        fruits f 
        where f.id in (select group_concat(fruit_id) from fruits_seasons where monsoon = 1);
```

*My expected result*

| name | price |
| --- | --- |
| lemon | 15.00 |
| carrot | 35.00 |
| papaya | 18.00 |
| custard apple | 15.00 |
| mango | 25.00 |
| apple | 25.00 |

*The result I got*

| name | price |
| --- | --- |
| lemon | 15.00 |

**What is the reason am I getting a single row instead of multiple?**

Comment: Why don't you just use `f.id in (select fruit_id ...`?

Comment: I usually seen result set of mysql in server as key value pair, maybe that could a reason why I did not try something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` returns a string which is a comma separated list of values, so your code is equivalent to:

```
WHERE f.id IN ('2,8,9,11,13,15')
```

So, you compare the `id`, which is an integer to the only item in the list which is a string and in this case [MySql tries to convert the string to an integer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html).
The result of the conversion is `2` (the starting part of the string which can be successfully converted to an integer) and finally your code is equivalent to:

```
WHERE f.id IN (2)
```

If you have to use `GROUP_CONCAT()` for your requirement, instead of the operator `IN` use the function [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT f.name, f.price
FROM fruits f 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(f.id, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(fruit_id) FROM fruits_seasons WHERE monsoon = 1));
```

But it's easier this way:

```
SELECT f.name, f.price
FROM fruits f 
WHERE f.id IN (SELECT fruit_id FROM fruits_seasons WHERE monsoon = 1);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=570db9a916e9f359db1eb9089cc83505).

Comment: Thanks you for explaining it so well. I came to know about type casting, find_in_set function and very importantly that I can straight forwardly write query in IN() in MySQL.